# What's the advantage of making a Sinatra/Rack app into a single, locally-executable file?

Tags: ruby, executable, sinatra

I was reading the [description](http://code.quirkey.com/vegas/) of Vegas, which is a gem that

> aims to solve the simple problem of
>   creating executable versions of
>   Sinatra/Rack apps.

I didn't know this was a problem that needed to be solved.

The reason this seems of dubious benefit is because of this:

```
Now if you run ./my_app it should:

    * find an appropriate rack handler (thin. mongrel)
    * find an available port
    * launch the app in a browser
    * put itself in the background
    * write a .pid and a .url file
```

Isn't it already extremely easy to run a Sinatra application? You just type

```
ruby my_app.rb
```

and all of those same things happen except for the app being a background process.

**Why do you need an executable file for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like a convenience wrapper around Sinatra/Rack, except for daemonizing (`.pid` and `.url` are most likely to "find" it again) and launching a browser this doesn't seem to have any advantage over bare Sinatra/Rack.